# How to pass nested JSON object to useState in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, json

```
const TreesList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    treeData: {
      name: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "3",
        },
        {
          name: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "5",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "7",
                },
                { name: "6" },
              ],
            },
            {

            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    TobeAdd: [
      { node: "2", dire: "left",prev:null },
      { node: "3", dire: "right",prev:null },
      { node: "5", dire: "right", prev: "2" },
      { node: "6", dire: "left", prev: "5" },
      { node: "7", dire: "right", prev: "5" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    treeData: {
      name: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "3",
            },
            {
              name: "4",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "5",
                },
                {}
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "6",
          children: [
            {},
            {
              name: "7",
              children: [
                {},
                {
                  name: "8",
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    TobeAdd: [
        { node: "2", dire: "left",prev:null},
        { node: "6", dire: "right",prev:null },
        { node: "3", dire: "left", prev: "2" },
        { node: "4", dire: "right", prev: "2" },
        { node: "5", dire: "left", prev: "4" },
        { node: "7", dire: "right", prev: "6" },
        { node: "8", dire: "right", prev: "7" },
      ],
  },
];

export default TreesList;
```

this is App.js:
[image]

have I passed JSON object in correct way getting this error:

[image]

I tried forLoop to pass target JSON object to useState, but didn't work.
I am new to React and for this code its giving this error
Dont understand where getting wrong, please help

Comment: The problem is not the JSON only `TreeList[treeid]`. Check what is `treeid` by adding console.log. I bet it's a kind of object.

Comment: Screenshots are terrible for sharing code and errors, because they require reading and then typing what's read out and then re-reading both to verify it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

First get by id and get by an index are two different operations.

```js
const TreesList = [
  {
    id: 100,
    treeData: {
      name: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "3",
        },
        {
          name: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "5",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "7",
                },
                { name: "6" },
              ],
            },
            {

            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    TobeAdd: [
      { node: "2", dire: "left",prev:null },
      { node: "3", dire: "right",prev:null },
      { node: "5", dire: "right", prev: "2" },
      { node: "6", dire: "left", prev: "5" },
      { node: "7", dire: "right", prev: "5" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    treeData: {
      name: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "3",
            },
            {
              name: "4",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "5",
                },
                {}
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "6",
          children: [
            {},
            {
              name: "7",
              children: [
                {},
                {
                  name: "8",
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    TobeAdd: [
        { node: "2", dire: "left",prev:null},
        { node: "6", dire: "right",prev:null },
        { node: "3", dire: "left", prev: "2" },
        { node: "4", dire: "right", prev: "2" },
        { node: "5", dire: "left", prev: "4" },
        { node: "7", dire: "right", prev: "6" },
        { node: "8", dire: "right", prev: "7" },
      ],
  },
];
//this will returen tree by index
//console.log(TreesList[1]);

//if you want to get by id
const filtered =TreesList.filter((t)=>t.id==100);
console.log(filtered.length>0?filtered[0]:[]);
```

The second point is
It is better to separate state initialization and assign TreesList

ex =>

```
const [tree,setTree]=[];
useEffect(() => {
console.log(id);
//you can check ID and tree data exist here
const filtered = TreesList.filter((t)=>t.id==id)?[0];
if(id && filtered.length>0)
   setTree(filtered[0])
}, [id,TreesList]);
```